# Colorbox Slideshow not Working on Mobile Devices

Tags: media, javascript

I have a Colorbox slideshow that doesn't want to work on mobile devices. Instead of opening up the slideshow modal on an image click, the browser opens the image in a new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of Colorbox is to disable mobile functionality when the device's max width exceeds 480px. This functionality can be disabled with the Mobile detection option in ***Configuration > Media > Colorbox > Advanced settings***.

[image]